# SOQL: Count number of child records

Tags: soql

This is a basic SOQL question. I have a number of Application (custom) objects that are children to the User (standard) object.

I want to count the number of Applications associated with each User.

Looking at the documentation I can get a query like this to work:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT id FROM Applications__r) FROM User
```

But how do I get a count associated with each User?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use your current query and get the size attribute of the list after the query finishes:

```
List<User> users = [SELECT Name, (SELECT id FROM Applications__r) FROM User];
for (User u : users) {
    // do something with it...
    u.Applications__r.size();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use an [AggregateResult query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) which would query the child and group by the User Id lookup.  This would not retrieve any information about Users that don't have any Applications, though. Also, if the User field is not required, all Applications that don't have a User would be put in the grouping where User__c is null.

```
// Assumes you have a Lookup called User__c
Map<Id, Integer> userAppCountMap = new Map<Id, Integer>();
for (AggregateResult aggRes : [
      SELECT COUNT(ID) numApps, User__c userId
      FROM Application__c
      GROUP BY User__c
]) {
    Id userId = (Id) aggRes.get('userId');
    Integer numApps = (Integer) aggRes.get('numApps');
    userAppCountMap.put(userId, numApps);
}
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't capture the fact that some users might have 0 cases assigned. But the second one works great.

Comment: Do not use 1st one unless you're sure the numbers will be low. For bigger cases the inner query starts to lie and limit itself to say 200 rows when the real amount can be bigger. It's bit similar to how related list by default show first 5 records and you need to explicitly click to get more.

Comment: Hmm. There probably will be more than 200 applications. Is there any documentation for what you're describing?

Comment: From http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm "The row counts from these relationship queries contribute to the row counts of the overall code execution."

Comment: What if I want the query to return count of Applications against each "user name" in an Ascending/Descending order?

Comment: @PeterKnolle in the aggregate query, can you return the aggregate count that is greater than say 1?

Answer (score 10):

I know that Ranga Ranga already posted an answer to the question but their answer is a generic pseudo query. Here is a much simpler query that you can actually copy and paste right into SoqlXplorer and it will run.

```
select User__c, count(Id)
from Applications__c
group by User__c
```

Works fine with other objects as well:

```
select AccountId, count(Id)
from Contact
group by AccountId
```

Note you might have to add a `limit` or `having` clause to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 8):

It is very easy to do with Apex code, But nobody put an SOQL queried Answer here, I searched in many blogs regarding this. Finally, I did it alone. Here it helps...

```
SELECT (Parent_Api_Name_In_Child_Object),
COUNT(ID)
   (Child_Realtionship_Name__r.Parent_Fields....)
     FROM (Child_Object_Api_Name) GROUP BY (Parent_Api_Name_Child_Object,
                        Parent Fields with API Names) HAVING COUNT(ID){>,<,=,{Optional}}
```

Comment: It seems like you just pasted the stuff from some other place, can you plz recheck and correct to make it readable. No need to add name and numbr.

Comment: This is great, thanks.  I needed all records where the number of attachments was higher than 100.  Used your template, and it worked nicely:   select parentid, count(id) from Attachment group by ParentId having count(ID) > 100 order by count(id) desc

Comment: Maybe a real example would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

SELECT AccountId,Account.Name, COUNT(Id) ContactCount FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId,Account.Name HAVING COUNT(Id) > 10

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Your contribution is welcome. However, there are a few issues with your answer. *Firstly*, it is barely any different (in my opinion not substantially enough so) than *d512*'s answer from 4 years ago. *Secondly*, "code dump" answers are frowned upon on SFSE - the *why* (explanation) is often as or more important than the *how* (code). So please edit your answer to add *why* it is different from the other answers and how that could be useful.